# Firebase Cloud Functions - How to wait for a function while within a exports?

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Using Firebase Cloud Functions I am trying to expand a uri that is in a firestore document and replace it with the expanded uri.

I am using the tall npm package  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tall) which is working well, I just am not able to get the resulting expanded uri into my object to put back into firestore.

I believe its not returning before the rest of my function finishes and therefore not giving me the data. When I tried using the example on the page for async and use await firebase gives an error.

I am assuming I am missing something very simple but after a solid day uploading to cloud functions, testing, and trying again I am beyond frustrated.

What am I missing?

```
exports.addonSanitized = functions.firestore
  .document('addons/{addonId}')
  .onCreate(doc => {
    const addonId = doc.id;
    const addon = doc.data();

    const expandedLink = tall(addon.link)
      .then(unshortenedUrl => console.log('Tall url', unshortenedUrl))
      .catch(err => console.error('AAAW ', err));

    const sanitized = {
      summary: `${expandedLink}`
    };

    return admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('addons')
      .doc(addonId)
      .update(sanitized)
      .then(doc => console.log('Entry Sanitized', doc));
  });
```

I expect the expandedLink to return the expanded link. What is being inputed into the document is [object Promise]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting "[object Promise]" because the value of `expandedLink` is a `Promise`.

The value you actually want is `unshortenedUrl`. You can only access that value inside the `then()` where it exists, so you need to return the `tall` Promise instead, and have your other return statement inside `then()`.

Potentially something like this (untested):

```
exports.addonSanitized = functions.firestore
  .document('addons/{addonId}')
  .onCreate(doc => {
    const addonId = doc.id;
    const addon = doc.data();

    return tall(addon.link)
      .then(unshortenedUrl => {
        console.log('Tall url', unshortenedUrl)
        const sanitized = {
          summary: `${unshortenedUrl}`
        };
        return admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('addons')
          .doc(addonId)
          .update(sanitized)
          .then(doc => console.log('Entry Sanitized', doc));
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('AAAW ', err));

  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I managed to get it working using your example. I still need to do some refactoring later but for now I am able to unwrap these links.